# Best Approach to record/log errors in db

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to Asp.net Core, and am sorting a mechanism to save my exceptions to database. below is my error handler config.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/ErrorLogger");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/ErrorLogger/GError", "?statusCode={0}");
```

while my errorlogger controller looks like following.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        var code = HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
        if (exception != null)
        {
            string errorMsg = "";
            try
            {
                _logger.Error = exception.Error;
                var log = _logger.ErrorLog;
                log.CreatedBy = _user.UserID;
                _db.ResetDB();
                await _db.AddAsync(log);
                errorMsg = $"Error Code:{ code }x{log.ErrorLogId:00000}<br/>" +
                    "An error occured during processing your request, " +
                    $"please note error code and contact IT Help desk for resolution.";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _db.ResetDB();
                errorMsg = $"Error Code:{ code }xUn-known<br/>" +
                    "An error occured during processing your request, " +
                    $"please note error code and contact IT Help desk for resolution.";
            }
            ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = errorMsg;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(code >= 200 && code <= 204))
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(GError), new { statusCode = code });
        }
        ViewData["Referrer"] = Request?.GetTypedHeaders()?.Referer?.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        return View();
    }
```

now this works fine, but when I try to call an error throwing function from ajax like fillowing

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ad/locfiles/clf?lfId=' + id,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    toastr.success(data.message);
                    dt.ajax.reload();
                }
                else {
                    toastr.error(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
```

and my controller method that throws/or produce error is like following

```
public async Task<IActionResult> clf(long lfId)
    {
        var lf = await _db.FindAsync<LocFile>(lfId);
        if (lf != null)
        {
            try
            {
                lf.LFTypeId = 1500;
                lf.ClosingDate = DateTime.Now;
                lf.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                lf.UpdatedBy = _user.UserID;
                await _db.UpdateAsync(lf);
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "File closed successfully." });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "An un-known error occured while closing file." });
    }
```

I am unable to response back to my ajax call to toaster an error message.
if I skip throwing error, than I am unable to store it in database, but if throw it, than how can I toastr error message?

Comment: What does `unable to response back to my ajax call to toaster an error message` mean? Can't you return your custom error message to ajax when `lf=null`?

Comment: Or do you want to return the error message from the `catch` module to ajax? You can call your database storage logic in the `catch` module, then `return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });`

Comment: when i `throw` in catch, my `ErrorLoggerController` handle it automatically as I configured in `Startup.cs`, so i don't need to write logic each time in catch